# NDB: How can I retrieve next/previous entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm writing an application for a factory where I need to provide a way for the user to retrieve the next (or previous) entity of a kind in NDB and can't figure out how to do this. Any help /tips will be appreciated!

Assume I have the following simplified model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Product(ndb.Model):
    prod_id = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    prod_desc = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    prod_units = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    ... other properties
```

To allow the user to find a particular product I use the query below  ('find' comes from a form filled in by the user).

```
Products_Str = 'Products'   # The string ID for the common products ancestor

...
def get_products_key(products_key_str = Products_Str):
    return ndb.Key('Products', Products_Str)

class DisplayProduct(BaseHandler):  # Displays a product found on exact prod_id property 
def post(self):
    search_key = self.request.get('find')
    find_query = Product.query(Product.prod_id == search_key, ancestor = get_products_key()).get()
    ... here I display the one result of the query, i.e. the requested product
```

So far so good: I provide the user with a way to find a specific product based on code (or description).

Now I need to place two buttons on the display page named "previous" and "next" and I can't figure out how to retrieve the next and previous products.

I would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Found the anwer here :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822852/how-to-get-latest-and-adjacent-records-from-the-datastore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get latest and adjacent records from the datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822852/how-to-get-latest-and-adjacent-records-from-the-datastore)